# How can I manipulate one object in the arrayList without messing with the other ones?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I created 4 types of Pod classes:

1. Kitchen Pod
2. Hygiene Pod
3. Sleeping Pod
4. Social Pod

Each Pod has a limit of people they can take (Kitchen limit = 8, hygiene limit = 2, sleeping limit = 2, social limit = 10). When the limit is reached, I have to create another Pod of the same type to store the remainder. I have an `ArrayList` that stores `Pod` objects in a different class called `SpaceStationTester`. I am trying to set a specific capacity (number of people) to only the first of each type of `Pod` (by calling a capacity setter method that is in each Pod class) without messing with the others (assuming I have more than one pod of "Kitchen", "Sleeping", etc..)

But instead, I end up setting the new capacity for all of the Kitchen, Sleeping, Social and Hygiene pods.

How can I only set the capacity of the first of each kind? Here is my SpaceStation class:

```
public class SpaceStationTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Step 1: Create space station that will support 15 colonists.
                   Report the configuration of all pods created. 
        */
        SpaceStation station = new SpaceStation(15);
        String configuration = station.getStationConfig();
        System.out.println(configuration);


        /* Step 2:  Assign colonists to pods as follows:

            5 are in social pods
            8 are in kitchen pods
            1 is in a hygiene pod
            1 is in a sleeping pod.

          Check the status of all pods and report it.
        */
        int socialAmount = 5;
        int kitchenAmount = 8;
        int hygieneAmount = 1;
        int sleepingAmount = 1;

        ArrayList<Pod> arr = new ArrayList<Pod>();
        arr.addAll(station.getPods()); //Adding everything from pods to arr
        Iterator<Pod> it = arr.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Pod x = it.next();
            if (x.getType() == "Kitchen Pod") {
                x.setCurrentCapacity(kitchenAmount);
            } else if (x.getType() == "Sleeping Pod") {
                x.setCurrentCapacity(sleepingAmount);
            } else if (x.getType() == "Hygiene Pod") {
                x.setCurrentCapacity(hygieneAmount);
            } else if (x.getType() == "Social Pod") {
                x.setCurrentCapacity(socialAmount);
            }
        }

        String status = station.checkStatus();
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Pod type:Kitchen Pod    Current capacity:8  Max capacity:8
Pod type:Kitchen Pod    Current capacity:8  Max capacity:8
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Sleeping Pod   Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Hygiene Pod    Current capacity:1  Max capacity:2
Pod type:Social Pod     Current capacity:5  Max capacity:10
Pod type:Social Pod     Current capacity:5  Max capacity:10
```

Comment: Do you have to use ArrayLists? You could always use arrays or just create a new ArrayList object.

Comment: I can only use arrayList @LoganKulinski

Comment: the isFull() method wouldnt work, they all start empty, so it would still add the new capacity to all @LoganKulinski

Comment: Are the `Pod` attributes `static`?

Comment: you can't compare strings reliably with `st1==st2`, you should use `st1.equals(st2)`

Comment: they are not static @EJP

Comment: Please post the code of the Pod class. Either you're adding the same object multiple times to the list or the attributes are static.

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because you don't have several of each type; you only have one of each type.   You probably assign the same reference to each element in the List.  When you change that single instance all the List elements point to the same thing, so it appears that you've "messed them all up".

The solution is to create a new Pod type for each element in the List.  That way you can change one without affecting the others.

Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 3/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907239/how-can-i-manipulate-one-object-in-the-arraylist-without-messing-with-the-other/35907280#35907280
 */
public class Foo {
    private int value;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        foos.add(new Foo(1));
        foos.add(new Foo(2));

        System.out.println("before change: " + foos);
        foos.get(0).setValue(20);
        System.out.println("after  change: " + foos);
    }

    public Foo(int v) { this.setValue(v); }

    public void setValue(int v) { this.value = v; }

    public String toString() { return String.format("value: %d", this.value); }
}
```

As you can see, I changed one instance of `Foo` in my `List`; it had no effect on the state of the other.

Comment: I do have several of each type. They all inherit from a Pod class I have. As you see, When creating the SpaceStation Object, the integer 15 used as the parameter. In my SpaceStation class I created a for loop that created the required amount of Pods of each type to support 15 people

Comment: so If fro example, Kitchen Pod holds 8 at a time. So to hold 15 people, I created 2 Kitchen Pods and added them to the arraylist

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put flag for each kind to check if the capacity is set.
For example:

```
    boolean isKitchenPodSet = false, isSleepingPodSet = false,
    isHygienePodSet = false, isSocialPodSet = false;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Pod x = it.next();
        if (x.getType() == "Kitchen Pod" && !isKitchenPodSet ) {
            x.setCurrentCapacity(kitchenAmount);
            isKitchenPodSet = true;    
        } else if (x.getType() == "Sleeping Pod" && !isSleepingPodSet ) {
            x.setCurrentCapacity(sleepingAmount);
            isSleepingPodSet = true;
        } else if (x.getType() == "Hygiene Pod" && !isHygienePodSet ) {
            x.setCurrentCapacity(hygieneAmount);
            isHygienePodSet = true;
        } else if (x.getType() == "Social Pod" && !isSocialPodSet ) {
            x.setCurrentCapacity(socialAmount);
            isSocialPodSet  = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just create a separate `ArrayList` for each kind of Pod and use it on your `iterator` instead of setting the capacity there?

```
List<Pod> kitchenPods = new ArrayList<Pod>();
// ... do the same for the remaining kinds of pod

while (it.hasNext()) {
        Pod x = it.next();
        if (x.getType() == "Kitchen Pod") {
            kitchenPods.add(x);
        } else if (x.getType() == "Sleeping Pod") {
            sleepingPods.add(x);
        } else if (x.getType() == "Hygiene Pod") {
            hygienePods.add(x);
        } else if (x.getType() == "Social Pod") {
           socialPods.add(x);
        }
    }
```

Now that you have them separated, you can load the corresponding pod. (creating a method for each may be good idea)

```
    for(int i=0; i < kitchenPods.size(); i++){
         if (kitchenPods.get(i).getCapacity < kitchenPods.get(i).getMaxCapacity){
                 //  Load them up!
          }
    }

    // do the same for the rest of the Pods
```

When you have them all loaded up, you can add them all up into a single List in case you need to merge them.

Not sure if this is what you need, but i hope this helps.